# How to prevent gpg-agent from timing out during passphrase collection?

Tags: encryption, gnupg, gpg-agent

I'm calling out to `gpg2` in a CLI script for symmetrical encryption of a local file. It appears to have `gpg-agent` prompt for a passphrase via some CLI, text based UI. As long as I'm around to enter the passphrase everything works fine. If I'm not, however, it eventually fails out with this message:

```
gpg-agent[15338]: command get_passphrase failed: Operation cancelled
gpg: cancelled by user
gpg: error creating passphrase: Operation cancelled
gpg: symmetric encryption of `XXXX.tar' failed: Operation cancelled
```

Is there any way to turn off this timeout entirely?

I would want the passphrase prompt to remain on the screen indefinitely until I enter something.

Answer (score 4):

The solution has been found here: https://dev.gnupg.org/T3240

The delay is caused by the pinentry querying the GNOME keyring. Add `no-allow-external-cache` to your **gpg-agent.conf**, or remove `gnome-keyring`, and kill currently running gpg-agent: `gpgconf --kill gpg-agent`

Comment: Yeah, just need forced kill gpg-agent and re-try again!

Answer (score 2):

In gpg-agent.conf (see [gpg-agent(1)](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg-devel/Agent-Options.html)), try the following options:

```
pinentry-timeout 0
pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-curses --timeout 0
```

(You might find `pinentry-tty` somewhat nicer to use though.)

Comment: `gpg-agent[22779]: /Users/xxx/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf:1: invalid option`

Comment: I had GnuPG 2.0.x installed and `gpg-agent` did not support these options. I've upgraded to 2.1.x which does support these options.

Answer (score 2):

Q: "*How to prevent gpg-agent from timing out during passphrase collection?"*

A: A specific case is a usage of `gpg` in an `ssh` session. The configuration below enables *gpg-agent* also within an `ssh` session. In particular

- *no-grab* allows cut&paste
- *no-allow-external-cache* disables any keyrings
- *pinentry-curses* asks for the password in the terminal instead of default *pinentry* asking in the remote (in the case of ssh) desktop window.
- The time to live *ttl* (5,6) is set to 24 hours. This way, it’s not necessary to re-enter the password when, for example, a cron, which invokes a script with gpg-agent, is run daily.

```sh
shell> cat ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf
no-grab 
no-allow-external-cache 
pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-curses
default-cache-ttl 86400
max-cache-ttl 86400
```

Comment: i know it's weird but thank you for giving some clues for me to fix another bug with `pinentry` where `gpg-agent` keeps yelling  `command 'PKSIGN' failed: Operation cancelled <Pinentry>`. Thanks a lot. For those who have similar issue, try to add that  `pinentry-curses` to your config file.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me (gpg 2.1.11) was just to set the `pinentry-timeout` option to a big value (like 24 hours), by adding the following to my `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` file:

```
# time until pinentry closes in seconds
pinentry-timeout 86400
```